# How does my Site look in other countries

Tags: javascript

I just made some changes to my website, it will display different greeting text for different continents, I have used Google's API to get location of the user

```
region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
countrycode = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
```

But now i want to test this, so is there any way that i can access my site with the IP of another continent or country, or any other solution for this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this based on geolocation? If you are localising for language, which is the usual case, you should use the `Accept-Language` settings instead.

Comment: I didnt localise for language, it was just that my greeting has different features for different continents, the only solution i could get was asking my friend to visit the site who lives abroad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an online proxy service, located in the country you want to test for. A list of free online proxies can be found at http://proxy.org/.

Comment: not working for me atleast :s

Comment: This is a good solution, might work in most of the cases but for me it didnt, coz i was using google's ajax api to get the location on client-side but on a proxy server the google code wasnt working, google.loader.ClientLocation was null.
For more simpler problems other than mine you can get a list of proxy servers sorted with respect to countries on http://proxy.org/proxies_sorted.shtml,

Answer (score 5):

I've built a tool that you might find useful, called [GeoPeeker](http://www.geopeeker.com/). In my own testing I found proxies to be unreliable, so I designed GeoPeeker to use actual servers that render a site and provide DNS information from various remote locations. It's handy for troubleshooting CDN and DNS issues.

It's also free to use and there are no ads.

Comment: Just used it to test the regioning on my site's phone number, really handy, thanks.